# asterisk in ksh variable

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

abc.txt as

```
* This
Data1
Dat2
* Comment
data2
data3
```

When $line gets * as first char it does not work. It echoes garbage.

I tried various way but couldn't  make it to work, how to check '*' in ksh varaible

```
while read line
do
        fchar=`echo "$line" | cut -c 1-1`
        #echo $fchar

    if [[ ${char} = "*" ]]; then
                continue
        fi

    if [[ ${char} = "#" ]]; then
                continue
        fi

        echo ${line} >> stuff.txt

done<$abc.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: A handy tool to use is shellcheck (http://www.shellcheck.net/#).  It will call out a variety of basic hints on how you can improve your script.  e.g. the use of double quotes around the variable in `${line} >> stuff.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Needs more quotes.

```
echo "$line" >>stuff.txt
```

...not

```
echo $line >>stuff.txt
```

...as the latter string-splits and glob-expands contents of the line, so it replaces `*` with a list of files in the current directory, replaces `foo[bar]` with `foob` if a file by that name exists, etc.

---

By the way, you'd be better off opening `stuff.txt` only once, not re-opening it every single time you want to add a new line. That'd look like this:

```
while read; do
  fchar=${REPLY:0:1}
  [[ "$fchar" = "*" ]] && continue
  [[ "$fchar" = "#" ]] && continue
  printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
done >stuff.txt <abc.txt
```

---

By the way, you could also do this trivially with grep:

```
grep -E -v '^[*#]' <abc.txt >stuff.txt
```

Comment: I've got a fever and the only cure, is more quotes.

Comment: ...by the way, quotes on the left-hand side of a `[[ $foo = $bar ]]` expression are actually optional; I put them here to encourage leaning towards too many quotes, rather than too few, whenever in doubt.